# Why does var foo = null compile

Tags: kotlin

I am starting with Kotlin and trying to understand something.

`var foo: String = null` does not compile as expected.

`var foo: String? = null` should be the correct syntax and compile as expected.

So why does `var foo = null` compile??

Comment: Why do you expect it *not* to compile? Kotlin is just inferring a suitable type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of `foo` in this case will be inferred to `Nothing?`, which is a very special type. In short, `Nothing` is a type that is a subtype of every type in Kotlin (therefore `Nothing?` is a subtype of every nullable type), has no instances, and can be used as a return type for functions that can never return.

Even though `Nothing` can have no instances, `null` itself of type `Nothing?`, which is why it can be assigned to any nullable variable.

You can learn more in depth about `Nothing` in the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), in [this excellent Medium article](https://medium.com/@quiro91/nothing-else-matters-in-kotlin-994a9ef106fc), and in [this article](http://natpryce.com/articles/000818.html) that covers the overall Kotlin type hierarchy.

Comment: why it infers to Nothing? instead of Any? ?

Comment: The compiler always infers the most concrete type it can - `Nothing?` is the most concrete type here, and `Any?` would be the least concrete (so the broadest) type overall. Imagine how annoying it would be if every variable was always inferred to be an `Any?`.

Comment: but in case var foo = 1, Nothing will be the most concrete type, however it will infer to Int, right?

Answer (score 5):

For `var foo = null`, the type is inferred to `Nothing?`, and is therefore valid syntax.

Comment: I.e. you can only store null in that variable.

Answer (score 4):

`var foo = null` is equivalent to `var foo:Nothing? = null`

similarly

`var foo = ""` is equivalent to `var foo:String = ""`

and slo

`var foo = 1` is equivalent to `var foo:Int = 1`

The compiler is smart enough to infer the type of `foo` from the right hand expression type.