# Creating method to return generic parameterized class

Tags: kotlin

Having a class:

```
abstract class Bird<T: Food>
```

and a subclass, where `Fish` extends `Food`:

```
class Falcon: Bird<Fish>()
```

How do I create a method that returns a `Bird`:

```
fun getBird(type: Int): Bird<Food> {
   if (type == SOME_CONSTANT) {
       return Falcon()
   } else {
      // Another bird
   }
}
```

Getting:

```
Type mismatch: Required Bird<Food>, found Falcon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options to solve this:

1. **Using declaration site variance.** This is preferred when possible.

   What you need for this to work is `Bird<Fish>` (which your `Falcon` is) to be a subtype of `Bird<Food>` (which you're returning). Since `Fish` is also a subtype of `Food`, what you need here is covariance, which you can specify for the type parameter with the `out` keyword:

   ```
   abstract class Bird<out T: Food>
   ```

   Now, you've added below in your comment that you have a mutable property of type `T?` in your base class, something like:

   ```
   abstract class Bird<out T: Food> {
       var food: T? = null
   }
   ```

   This is an issue for declaration site variance. If you want covariance to work, the type parameter can only be present in your class in `out` positions, meaning you can have functions that return `T`, but you can't have ones that accept `T` (in this case, that would be the setter of the property). Think about it: if you had a reference to a `Falcon` as a `Bird<Food>` because you got it from the `getBird` function, you could suddenly feed it any `Food`, not just `Fish`. This would break type safety. Which gets us to the other solution...
2. **Using use site variance.**

   This is less ideal, but sometimes necessary (like apparently in your case, because of the mutable property of type `T?` in your base class. Credit for this solution goes to [@tynn's very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379106/4465208), but let me expand on it.

   You can mark covariance on just the return type of the function instead of the entire abstract class by making the function return a `Bird<out Food>`.

   ```
   fun getBird(type: Int): Bird<out Food>
   ```

   Doing this will let you have your `T` parameter in both `in` and `out` positions in your class, but prevent you from using any functions that take `T` (have it in the `in` position) on the `Bird` instances that you get from the `getBird` function.

   So you could do this after the change:

   ```
   println(getBird(1).food)
   ```

   But not this for any value of `newFood` that's not `null` (since a variable of type `Nothing?` is required here, which [only `null` is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44292923/4465208)):

   ```
   getBird(1).food = newFood
   ```

   This restriction of not being able to set the `food` property of the `Bird` returned by the function is what "restores" type safety in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I have a member variable `abstract var food: T?` in Bird class which is now gives me the error `Type parameter T is marked as out but occurs in invariant position of type T`

Comment: Indeed, this is a restriction if you want covariance to work, the type parameter can only be present in your class in `out` positions, so you can have functions that return `T`, but you can't have ones that accept `T` (in this case, that would be the setter of the property). Think about it: if you had a reference to your `Falcon` as a `Bird<Food>` because you got it from your function, you could feed it any `Food` and not just `Fish`. This would break type safety.

Comment: I've edited my answer to also include the idea by @tynn and to be more legible for people who find it in the future. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `out` variance on the return type of `getBird()`

```
fun getBird(type: Int): Bird<out Food>
```

Like this you can return birds with any food source without changing the `Bird` class.